# 'getInstance(io.realm.RealmConfiguration)' in 'io.realm.Realm' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context)'

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I'm adding a new database using realm and when i added

**`Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());`**

I get an error

> 'getInstance(io.realm.RealmConfiguration)' in 'io.realm.Realm' cannot
>   be applied to '(android.content.Context)'

How to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getDefaultInstance()` for create instance for Realm.

> `mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();`

You should set configuration of Realm in Application class.

```
public class MyRealmApp extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("myrealm.realm").build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);;
    }
}
```